# How to get javascript output in python BeautifulSoup or any other module

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In my attempt to make a scraper, I found a  website that uses javascript alot in its code, is it possible to retrieve the output of the script e.g.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Python</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src='test.js'></script>
<p> some stuff <br>
more stuff <br>
code <br>
video <br>
picture <br>
movie <br>
. <br>
. <br>
. <br>
</p>
<span>Your Number is:  </span>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(math(5, 10, 15));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

where "test.js" has:

```
function math (a, b, c) {return a * b * c * c * a * b * c + a + b +c - a;}
```

When I use BeautifulSoup it shows the code itself i.e:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(math(5, 10, 15));</script>
```

however i need to get "Your Number is:  8437480", i could get the text between span by using soup.span.get_text() however i cant get the number of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beautifulsoup just can't execute javascript code. I suggest you to integrate something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) into your **scraper**. If you can drop python, you **scraper** in PhantomJS

Comment: The point is doing it using python, isn't there a module that can excute javascript in python, where the function is from outside the source code, (I know how to include it in the code, but it'll be a pain)

Edit: Nevermind i found something called Ghost.py ill investigate further more.