# BeautifulSoup returns None even though the (div = "pendingcasescnts ng-scope") element exists

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape text from "Div" multiCLass  from the site : [Concluded Cases with Details](https://icsid.worldbank.org/en/Pages/cases/ConcludedCases.aspx?status=c)

[The example of the "div" class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJtYz.png)

It is not able to find the `div` element?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
url ="https://icsid.worldbank.org/en/Pages/cases/ConcludedCases.aspx?status=c"
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
cases_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ ="pendingcasescnts ng-scope")
print(len(cases_containers))
```

Comment: `ng-scope` means Angular, which is a JavaScript library. Does that div exist _in the HTML itself_, or is it created in the browser?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get javascript output in python BeautifulSoup or any other module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917163/how-to-get-javascript-output-in-python-beautifulsoup-or-any-other-module)

Comment: @Chris i think  that the "div"  exist in the html  itself , you  can  verify by inspecting the site :  https://icsid.worldbank.org/en/Pages/cases/ConcludedCases.aspx?status=c

Comment: I wouldn't normally go off-site to understand your question (next time, please include _all_ relevant data so your question is self-contained), but I can tell you that the server response for page does _not_ contain a `<div>` with an `ng-scope` attribute. It must be created via JavaScript, in which case you should look at the proposed duplicate I gave above. (Try it yourself by disabling JavaScript and then trying to load the page.)

Comment: Chris is right , you need `selenium`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of scraping the HTML, you can observe that the page requests all of the information on the screen via a separate request which returns all of the data you need in JSON format. This can be converted to a Python dictionary using the `.json()` requests function.

The following shows how the JSON returned could be used to extract the `Case No`, `Subject` and `Sector` fields:

```
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
import requests

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)
r = requests.get('https://wbwcfe.worldbank.org/icsidext/service.svc/getbulkcasesbystatusid/json?id=cd28', verify=False)
data = r.json()

for case in data['GetBulkCasesByStatusIdResult']:
    print(f"Case No.: {case['caseno']}\nSubject: {case['subject']}\nSector: {case['econsector']}\n")
```

Giving you output cases looking like:

```
Case No.: CONC/18/1
Subject: Water services and electric power concession
Sector: Electric Power & Other Energy

Case No.: ARB/17/40
Subject: Hydrocarbon concession
Sector: Oil, Gas & Mining

Case No.: ARB/17/39
Subject: Hydrocarbon concession
Sector: Oil, Gas & Mining
```

The URL was found by using the Browser's network tools whilst loading the URL that was given in the question.

I recommend you print out `data` and study all of the fields that are available to you.

Comment: thank you Martin i  have the same result  with selenium  but  your solution is  more optimal